# NaN in result variable and calculation

Tags: javascript, variables, nan

I have been studying JavaScript and experiment with some things. I have build a small application (see code below). Everything is going well untill the function `eindResultaat()`. Here it seems that there is something with `resultaat3` (it is NaN) but I can not figure out why. `resultaat1` and `resultaat2` are getting processed in the same way and there it goes fine.

```js
var resultatenArray = [];
var eindcijfer, eRes1, eRes2, eRes3, resultaat1, resultaat2, resultaat3;

function berekening1() {
  resultaat1 = document.getElementById("eersteTentamen").value;
  console.log("Dit is resultaat1 " + resultaat1);

  if ((resultaat1 == "GR") || (resultaat1 == "gr")) {
    document.getElementById("res1").innerHTML = "Geen resultaat";
    resultaat1 = resultaat1 || 0;
    //eRes1 = 0.0;
  } else {
    let res1 = document.getElementById("res1");
    res1.innerHTML = resultaat1;
    res1.style.color = resultaat1 >= 5.5 ? 'green' : 'red';
    document.getElementById("res1").innerHTML = resultaat1;
    //eRes1 = resultaat1;
    resultatenArray.push(resultaat1);
    console.log(resultatenArray);
  }
}

function berekening2() {
  resultaat2 = document.getElementById("tweedeTentamen").value;
  console.log("Dit is resultaat2 " + resultaat2);

  if ((resultaat2 == "GR") || (resultaat2 == "gr")) {
    document.getElementById("res2").innerHTML = "Geen resultaat";
    eRes2 = 0.0;
  } else {
    let res2 = document.getElementById("res2");
    res2.innerHTML = resultaat2;
    res2.style.color = resultaat2 >= 5.5 ? 'green' : 'red';
    document.getElementById("res2").innerHTML = resultaat2;
    //eRes2 = resultaat2;
    resultatenArray.push(resultaat2);
    console.log(resultatenArray);
  }
}

function berekening3() {
  resultaat3 = document.getElementById("derdeTentamen").value;
  console.log("Dit is resultaat3 " + resultaat3);

  if ((resultaat3 == "GR") || (resultaat3 == "gr")) {
    document.getElementById("res3").innerHTML = "Geen resultaat";
    var resultaat3 = 0.0;
    //eRes3 = 0;
    console.log(resultaat3);
  } else {
    let res3 = document.getElementById("res3");
    res3.innerHTML = resultaat3;
    res3.style.color = resultaat3 >= 5.5 ? 'green' : 'red';
    document.getElementById("res3").innerHTML = resultaat3;
    //eRes3 = resultaat3;
    resultatenArray.push(resultaat3);
    console.log(resultatenArray);
  }
  console.log(isNaN(resultaat3));
}

function eindResultaat() {
  var aantalDeelTentamens = resultatenArray.length;
  console.log(aantalDeelTentamens);

  console.log("resultaten: " + resultaat1, resultaat2, resultaat3);
  //console.log("eRes resultaten:" + eRes1, eRes2, eRes3);

  //parseFloat(resultaat1);
  //parseFloat(resultaat2);
  //parseFloat(resultaat3);

  console.log(isNaN(resultaat1));
  console.log(isNaN(resultaat2));
  console.log(isNaN(resultaat3));
  eindcijfer = ((resultaat1 + resultaat2 + resultaat3) / aantalDeelTentamens).toFixed(1);
  //var eindcijfer = ((eRes1 + eRes2 + eRes3)/aantalDeelTentamens).toFixed(1);
  console.log(eindcijfer);
  console.log(isNaN(eindcijfer));

  document.getElementById("eindresultaat").innerHTML = eindcijfer;
}
```

```html
Resultaat <b>eerste</b> deeltentamen: <input type="text" value="" id="eersteTentamen"><input type="submit" name=buttonResultaat1 value="Resultaat bevestigen" onclick="berekening1()"><br><br> Resultaat <b>tweede</b> deeltentamen: <input type="text" value=""
  id="tweedeTentamen"><input type="submit" name=buttonResultaat2 value="Resultaat bevestigen" onclick="berekening2()"><br><br> Resultaat <b>derde</b> deeltentamen: <input type="text" value="" id="derdeTentamen"><input type="submit" name=buttonResultaat3
  value="Resultaat bevestigen" onclick="berekening3()"><br><br>

<hr> Resultaat <b>eerste</b> deeltentamen: <span id="res1"></span><br> Resultaat <b>tweede</b> deeltentamen: <span id="res2"></span><br> Resultaat <b>derde</b> deeltentamen: <span id="res3"></span><br><br>

<hr>
<br>
<input type="submit" name=eindresultaat value="Bereken eindresultaat" onclick="eindResultaat()"><br><br>

<b>Het eindresultaat is: </b> <span id="eindresultaat"></span>
```

Comment: @cloned Your edit changed the name attribute of the buttons (from `name = buttonResultaat1` to `name=b uttonResultaat1`)

Comment: _"`resultaat1` and `resultaat2` are getting processed in the same way"_ - No. You've made a small but important change which broke your script. Remove the `var` in `var resultaat3 = 0.0;` -> Typo

Comment: @Andreas Sorry that was not my intention, I fixed this now!

Comment: @cloned You've change the `name` attribute of all buttons, not only the one from my comment

Comment: @Andreas thank you for setting this up right. I have removed the var at var resultaat3 = 0,0; but still not understand why it is processed as a NaN to the calculation of the average.

Comment: If you fixed the `var` then it won't end as `NaN`. If you run your example _with_ `var` you will see in your `console.log()`s that `resultaat3` is `undefined`. And any math operation with `undefined` will result in `NaN`

Comment: @Andreas thank you. But now it says in my console that `eindcijfer` is `undefined` although the formula of the average seems correct.

Comment: That's not possible. It will either be the string representation of a number or the script will throw an error.

Comment: @Andreas see a screenshot of what I see [https://i.imgur.com/aEy8PwB.png]

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, it was deleting the `var` at some places so the code works. No I am busy with what to do if someone makes 2 test in stead of 3. So the average must be calculated over 2 tests.